# Method not entered in test case, works when ran normally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I have a very weird issue and I am clueless as to what is causing this behaviour.

I will provide the relevant code of two classes, to keep this short.

Class A has a method that gets an xml document and puts that in an XDocument object, it uses a method from class B for this. Then it uses a different but similar method from class B to add some additional xml to the XDocument.

For some reason, when I run the test cases, the second method from Class B is never entered. Instead, it gives back null.

Here is the code:

First call to a method in class B, from class A

```
// Get view (xml) for current supplier
XDocument navigationView = ProductBUS.GetProductNavigationXDocument(suppID, viewName, selectedProductNavigationView);
```

Second call to a method in class B, from class A (this is the faulty one)

```
if (true)
{
    navigationView = ProductBUS.AddOptionsToNavigationMenu(navigationView);
}
```

(The if(true) is placeholder code, will be changed in the future to a boolean value. This value needs to come from the DB, which is empty at this point.)

The methods in class B, 1 and 2 respectively.

```
public XDocument GetProductNavigationXDocument(Guid supplierID, String viewName, string selectedProductNavigationView)
{
        // TODO : implementing full scale DI
        INavigationViewFactory factory = new NavigationViewFactory();
        INavigationView navigationXml = factory.Create(NavigationViewTypes.Product);

        return navigationXml.GetNavigationXDocument(supplierID, viewName, selectedProductNavigationView);
}
```

And the second one (which is never entered)

```
public XDocument AddOptionsToNavigationMenu(XDocument menu)
{

        menu.Element(XmlNames.NodeNames.MenuItems).Add(
                new XElement(XmlNames.NodeNames.MenuItem,
                   new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.ID, "27301D05-EBBB-4F39-AC74-B0E944F26C52"),
                   new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.DefaultName, "Options"),
                   new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.NameTranslationID, "9999"),
                   new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.DisplayMode, "Options"),
                   new XElement(XmlNames.NodeNames.MenuItem,
                           new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.ID, "27301D05-EBBB-4F39-AC74-B0E944F26C57"),
                           new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.NameTranslationID, "9999"),
                           new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.DefaultName, "Notifications"),
                           new XElement(XmlNames.NodeNames.Subscriptions,
                           new XElement(XmlNames.NodeNames.Subscription,
                                new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.ID, "7"),
                                new XAttribute(XmlNames.AttributeNames.DefaultName, "Subscriptions"))))));


        return menu;
}
```

I put breakpoints before, on and after the method call as well as inside of the method. If I run the application, I can debug right through the method. But when I run some test cases, that cover this bit of code, they method call is never entered. Instead, the code equals navigationView to null. I fixed this by putting the method's code in the first class, but I'd like to know why this is an issue.

### EDIT

Here is the code of one of the test cases that causes the faulty behavior when tested.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetProductDetailNavigationModel_ProductWith3FieldValuesAnd2Documents_MappedObjectIsNotNull()
    {
        // Arrange
        DDSInterfaceBlock.Current.IsImpersonated = false;
        Domain.Supplier supplier = new Domain.Supplier().Init();
        Domain.User user = new Domain.User().Init().Create();
        Domain.Language language = new Domain.Language().Init();
        Domain.Product product = new Domain.Product().Init().LinkSupplier(supplier);

        Domain.ProductOverview.ProductDetail productDetail = ArrangeProductDetailData(supplier, user, language, product);
        XDocument document = ArrangeXDocument(productDetail);

        ProductDetail svc = new ProductDetail();
        IProduct bus = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IProduct>();

        bus.Stub(t => t.GetProductNavigationXDocument(supplier.Id, null, string.Empty))
                       .IgnoreArguments()
                       .Return(document);

        bus.Stub(t => t.GetProductDetail(supplier.Id, user.Id, product.Id, language.Id, language.Id))
                       .IgnoreArguments()
                       .Return(productDetail);

        svc.ProductBUS = bus;

        svc.UserBUS = MockRepository.GenerateMock<BUS.Interfaces.IUser>();
        svc.UserBUS
            .Stub(t => t.CheckIfUserInPRAGroup(Guid.Empty))
            .IgnoreArguments()
            .Return(false);

        // Act
        Domain.ProductOverview.ProductDetailNavigationModel result
            = svc.GetProductDetailNavigationModel(supplier.Id, user.Id, product.Id, language.Id, language.Id);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Comment: Is the second class in a different assembly?

Comment: A different namespace.

Comment: But is it in a different project?  If so there might be a chance that your test cases are running with a different version.

Comment: No it is the same project. And if it were, wouldn't it throw an error if I ran the project too?

Comment: Do you have the code for the test cases - are you mocking any objects?

Comment: Yes, the objects are temporarily put in the DB and used for that. There is a unit test DB for that. Everything used works. When I put the code that sits in the method, in the first class. Everything works. It is just that it can't reach the method for some reason.

Comment: What are using to create the unit tests can you post the code?

Comment: I added a unit test to the post. This is one of the tests that causes the behavior.

Comment: Could it be because you have a stub for GetProductNavigationXDocument, but there is not sub for AddOptionsToNavigationMenu

Comment: You might be right, I'm testing it now.

Comment: You were right, this was the issue. Do I delete this question now? Or what is SE protocol?

Comment: I have added the comment as an answer you make it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you have a stub for GetProductNavigationXDocument, but there is not sub for AddOptionsToNavigationMenu